# Чтение из файла в питон без пробела

Tags: python, текст

[image: условие задачи]
Есть цикл школьных задач, решил начать их делать на питоне. До этого никогда не работал с файлами, используя питон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как занести в 3 переменные 3 числа, записанных во входном текстовом файле через пробел. 
Естественно, в итоге должны быть 3 переменные числового типа.

Вывод я примерно представляю как делать, но если не лень, можете написать и это )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычное чтение файла.
Для разделения через пробел используется метод `split()`, по умолчанию у него как раз разделителем является пробел, так что в аргументации не нуждается.

`filename` - имя вашего файла. Можете указать любой путь, как относительный, так и абсолютный.

```py
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b, c = line.split()
```

`a, b, c` - имена ваших переменных, можете назвать их как хотите

Comment: `split` без аргументов разбивает по любым пробельным символам (пробелам, табам, переносм строк...), причем несколько идущих подряд считает одним разделителем.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, теперь я знаю больше)

Comment: Функцию `open` можно немного упростить. Режим `r` (чтение) - это режим по умолчанию. То есть можно просто `open("filename.txt")`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 явное лучше неявного, не? Мне вот весьма лениво помнить, какой там режим по умолчанию)

Comment: А если в первой строке 1 число, а во второй 4, разделенных пробелом?

Comment: @OlehChaika возможно не так вас понял, но данный скрипт написан конкретно для присваивания трёх значений, как вам и было необходимо. Однако, используя механизм инструмента, что я описал выше, не составит труда присвоить сколько угодно и чего угодно.